# Prolog- nested if and else replacement

Tags: prolog

I have a grid which it's size(N,M) and my goal is to find the first cells that are in the same row and column 
example: if i have a cell in the middle of the board it will have four cells around it horizon and vertical

### First try

```
neighbor(X,Y,L):- Y1 is Y-1,Y2 is Y+1,X1 is X-1,X2 is X+1, % Assign values of the neighbors cells
in_grid(X,Y1),append([],[(X,Y1)],L1),%check and add to the list
in_grid(X,Y2),append(L1,[(X,Y2)],L2),
in_grid(X1,Y),append(L2,[(X1,Y)],L3),
in_grid(X2,Y),append(L3,[(X2,Y)],L).
```

this is how i define **in_grid** predicate

```
in_grid(X,Y):-size(N,M),between(1,N,X),between(1,M,Y).
```

*PS: size(N,M) is dynamic*

this code is working fine when the cell in the middle but it gives me False in other cells

### Another try

```
neighbor1(X,Y,L):- Y1 is Y-1,Y2 is Y+1,X1 is X-1,X2 is X+1, % Assign values of the neighbors cells
% it should works for grid's size(3,3)
((Y1=<0)->append([],[],L1),append([(X,Y1)],[],L1)), % check and add to the list
((Y2>=4)->append([],L1,L2),append([(X,Y2)],L1,L2)),
((X1=<0)->append([],L2,L3),append([(X1,Y)],L2,L3)),
((X2>=4)->append([],L3,L),append([(X2,Y)],L3,L)).
```

it is also gives me False and i don't know why ..
*i am using **SWI-Prolog 7.3.19***

Any Help plese

Answer (score 0):

I think you could keep it simpler: assuming that in size(N,M) N is Rows count, and M Columns count:

```
% G: list of lists of values
% R: row index
% C: column index
% N: a neighbour of R,C
neighbor(G,R,C,N) :-
  cell(G,R+1,C,N) ; cell(G,R,C+1,N) ; cell(G,R-1,C,N) ; cell(G,R,C-1,N).

cell(G,R,C,N) :- Y is R, X is C, nth1(X,G,Row), nth1(Y,Row,N).
```

*edit* example:

```
?- neighbor([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]],2,2,N).
N = f ;
N = h ;
N = d ;
N = b.
```

Comment: it didn't work for me this is what appears `G = [_G8388, [_G8397, _G8400, N|_G8404]|_G8392] .`
maybe i wasn't so clear i want to make sure that the neighbor cell is in the grid i mean when corner cell state for example it's going to give a cell out of grid which i don't want .... i see that **nth1**  should do this but i didn't understand how it has been used here @CapelliC

Comment: sorry but i still don't understand .. where the list of neighbors cells of a cell , the predicate is supposed to find all neighbors of one cell

Comment: f,h,d,b are the neighbours of e, located at coords 2,2